# Find the percentage of sales and returns by product sub-category. I need to display only top 5 sub-categories in terms of sales

Tags: sql-server

For this question, I have two tables and are as follows :

- prod_cat_info --- This table has the following columns:

  1. prod_cat : It contains the products' category names
  2. prod_cat_id : It contains the products' category ID. Note that every product category has been assigned a unique ID. For example :: Lets say I have following product categories Books,Sports,Electronics. So these 3 product categories will be assigned product category ID as 1,2 & 3 respectively.
  3. prod_subcat : It contains products' subcategories
  4. prod_subcat_id : It contains products' subcategories ID
     Now how this product subcategories are stored.

For example : Lets say for product category "Books", I have 3 product subcategories like "Novels", "Schoolbooks" & "Fiction". So in this case also, each and every product subcategory would be assigned an ID like 1,2,3 and so on.

- Transactions --- This is another table which has the following columns :

  1. total_amt : It contains amount paid by customer when a transaction took place.
  2. Qty : It contains quantities ordered by customer of a particular product.
  3. prod_subcat_id : It contains products' subcategories ID
  4. prod_cat_id : It contains the products' category ID.
  5. Cust_ID : It contains customer ID [Irrelevant column in case of this question]

> > **Note** Column Qty can contain both positive & negative values.
> >     For example : If Qty has positive value, Then it means an order was placed by customer.
> >     If Qty has negative value, then it means return request has been placed by customer. In this case value in total_amt column will also be negative.

I can easily find the top 5 product sub-categories in terms of sales using the following query I have written below. 
But I am not able to figure out how to calculate sales & returns by product sub-category. Though I feel it can be achieved using SELECT CASE WHEN statement in a way like case total_amt > 0 then "Here We can sum the positive values from total_amt column, multiply it by 100 & divide it by calculating the total sales value somehow from total_amt column"
Same thing We can do for returns like case total_amt < 0 then "100% minus the percentage of sales"

Can You guys help me in achieving the output of this question.

```
select top 5 Round(SUM(cast(total_amt as float)),2) as total_sales, 
P.prod_subcat 
from Transactions as T
INNER JOIN prod_cat_info as P
ON T.prod_subcat_code = P.prod_sub_cat_code
where T.Qty > 0
group by P.prod_subcat
order by total_sales desc
```

Note that I have used the cast function because column is of varchar type.
Also I have used where T.Qty > 0 in order to get the sum of only those values which are positive. Let me know if my understanding is correct in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You are right with the logic. You can calculate total sales, returns and profit like this.

```
select
[Subcategory] = P.prod_subcat,
[Sales] =   Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty > 0 then total_amt else 0 end as float)),2) , 
[Returns] = Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty < 0 then total_amt else 0 end as float)),2) , 
[Profit] =  Round(SUM(cast(total_amt as float)),2) , 

from Transactions as T
INNER JOIN prod_cat_info as P ON T.prod_subcat_code = P.prod_sub_cat_code
group by P.prod_subcat
```

Seeing that for returns total_amt will be negative [Profit] will be calculated corectly by just adding all total_amt values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select top 5
     P.prod_subcat [Subcategory] ,
      Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty > 0 then T.Qty else 0 end as float)),2)[Sales]  , 
     Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty < 0 then T.Qty   else 0 end as float)),2) [Returns] ,
    Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty > 0 then T.Qty else 0 end as float)),2)
                 - Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty < 0 then T.Qty   else 0 end as float)),2)[total_qty],
    ((Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty < 0 then T.Qty  else 0 end as float)),2))/
                  (Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty > 0 then T.Qty else 0 end as float)),2)
                 - Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty < 0 then T.Qty   else 0 end as float)),2)))*100[%_Returs],
    ((Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty > 0 then T.Qty  else 0 end as float)),2))/
                  (Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty > 0 then T.Qty else 0 end as float)),2)
                 - Round(SUM(cast( case when T.Qty < 0 then T.Qty   else 0 end as float)),2)))*100[%_sales]
    from tbl_Tran as T
    INNER JOIN prod_cat_info as P ON T.prod_subcat_code = P.prod_sub_cat_code
    group by P.prod_subcat
    order by [%_sales] desc
```

````
    --USE  Transactions at tbl_Tran
    --sales,
    --returns,
    --Total_qty=sale-returns ---- i am using -ve  becoz returns in already in -ve 
    --%sale=(sales/total_qty)*100
    --similar for % of returns
    ```
````

Answer (score -1):

Please check below answer, I have calculated top 5 sub category codes:

```
Select Top 5 prod_subcat_code,
Round(Sum(Cast(Case When Qty > 0 Then Qty Else 0 end as float)),2) Sales,
Round(Sum(Cast(Case When Qty < 0 Then Qty Else 0 end as Float)),2) asReturn,
Round(Sum(Cast(Case When Qty < 0 Then Qty Else 0 end as Float)),2)* 100/Round(Sum(Cast(Case When Qty > 0 Then Qty Else 0 end as float)),2) [asReturn%],
100 + Round(Sum(Cast(Case When Qty < 0 Then Qty Else 0 end as Float)),2)* 100/Round(Sum(Cast(Case When Qty > 0 Then Qty Else 0 end as float)),2) [Sales %]
from Transactions
group by prod_subcat_code 
Order By [Sales %]
```